# Sorting struct(ures)

Tags: c++, sorting

If i define a structure

```
struct dat{
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

and then I declare an array of that structure, i.e

```
dat array[10];
```

and then I sort the dat array array[i].a, i.e

```
std::sort((array.a),(array.a+10);
```

will this work?

And suppose after sorting, array[5].a goes to array[2].a, does array[5].b also go to array[2].b, if not how to do this using std library function sort.

Comment: Why not take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ ? You have there explained how to sort your own structures. Regarding question "will this work" I think that you can check that yourself.

Comment: i suspect you need to add a custom comparator function so that std::sort knows how to compare dat structs. You certainly cant say array.a

Comment: There is no "integer array"; there is a *dat* array,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort your data structure using the `std::sort()` algorithm, you could supply a comparator function as its third argument.

For example, to sort by the values of `dat.a`:

```
bool IntSorter (const dat& dat1, const dat& dat2) { return dat1.a < dat2.a; }
```

Then, you call sort like this:

```
std::sort(array, array + 10, IntSorter);
```

Also, you could refactor your code to avoid the magic number `10`, also to avoid duplicating it when referring to the one-past-last element in the call to `std::sort()`.

Comment: To avoid the magic number: in C++11, there is `std::begin(array)` and `std::end(array)`.  Pre-C++11, of course, every professional programmer had something equivalent in their toolkit, and used it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work as written.

First `std::sort((array.a),(array.a+10);` is incorrect.  `array.a` is not an array, and trying to treat it as one will certainly lead to some problems.

You would need to instead sort the array itself (`std::sort(array, array+10);`), but again, that won't work because you don't provide an overload of `opeartor<(dat)`.

You could provide one:

```
bool operator<(const dat& l, const dat& r)
{
   return l.a < r.a;
}
```

Then `std::sort(array, array+10);` would work as expected.

When you sort an object, it "all goes together".  That means that `dat::a` and `dat::b` will not be modified within a specific object, but the location of that object in the sorted array may be at a different index.

Comment: I am not sure what this means

Comment: Exactly what is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the array of structures according to the value of `a`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 
          [](dat const & lhs, dat const & rhs){return lhs.a < rhs.a;});
```

This will move the `b` values along with their corresponding `a` values, which I think is what you say you want. If you want the `b` values to stay where they are, then it would be somewhat messier. C++ doesn't provide any way to treat an array of `dat` as an array of `int`.

Comment: You could provide a custom swap, which ignores the `b` members.  `std::sort` is required to use the `swap` it finds using ADL.  (I would strongly recommend against this, however.  A `swap` which doesn't swap is going to confuse maintenance programmers to no end.)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `array.a` isn't a legal expression, since `array`
doesn't have an `a` member, and in fact, isn't even a struct.
If you want to sort the `dat` members by field `a`, you'll need
to either provide a custom ordering function (the preferred way,
especially if you have C++11 and can use lambda functions), or
define an `operator<` on `dat`.  If you just want to move the
`a` members during the sort, leaving the `b` members where they
are... you'd have to define a custom `swap` function as well:

```
void
swap( dat& lhs, dat& rhs )
{
    std::swap( lhs.a, rhs.a );
}
```

But this would be very wierd, and I'd suggest finding some other
way of organizing your data.